# Strange WPF issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I had two wpf forms, and I decided to combine them. I cut and paste one form into another, and then tried to do the same to the code. For some reason, it is saying "xxTextBox Does not exists in the current context" for every item I pasted. The controls and code that was already in place was unaffected.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here is the xml all generated by the design mode in VS2013, with all but one of the problem controls removed.

`<UserControl x:Class="EntryPanels.Ingredients"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="555" d:DesignWidth="925">
    <Grid Background="#FFBD9D9D">
          <TextBox Name="TBName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="367,183,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169"/>
           </Grid>
</UserControl>`

and a bit of the code:

`string Name = TBName.Text;`

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to where the message is showing?

Comment: Does it run?  did you try Rebuild?  How about closing VS and restarting it?  sometimes i seem to get "phantom" errors that don't really exist, but the error cache isn't cleared or something.

Comment: Try clearing your solution by right clicking on it. Also check namespaces and window names in both forms.

Comment: Yeah it must have been cached or something. Reloading the solution solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it run? did you try Rebuild? How about closing VS and restarting it? sometimes i seem to get "phantom" errors that don't really exist, but the error cache isn't cleared or something.